# Why and How Moly (Molybdenum) can melt at 800°C inside muffle furnace?

Tags: phase-transition, metals

I kept a ceramic cylinder wrapped in a Moly sheet. This whole thing was kept on an another Moly sheet inside muffle furnace. I ramped up the muffle furnace to 800°C in half an hour, kept there for half and hour and reduced it to room temperature in half an hour. I opened furnace at 352°C and saw that Moly has completely melted inside. I am not able to understand how and why this can happen. I am attaching here the melted Moly photo that I captured.
[image: Moly in its melted form with ceramic crucible inside muffle furnace]

Comment: Maybe it didn't melt but rather crinkled or shrunk or something like that? It was a thin sheet yes?

Comment: These "sheets"... Meant for one time use? If so, did someone maybe sell you counterfeit?

Comment: Yes, it was a thin sheet. It got melted as its form factor was totally changed. I wrapped Moly around that ceramic cylinder and on the bottom of it I kept a slightly big sheet of Moly also. @AXensen

Comment: No, earlier we checked it with EDAX and it was a Moly. Not a counterfeit. @SolomonSlow

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molybdenum)?

> Although its melting point is 2,623 °C (4,753 °F), molybdenum rapidly
> oxidizes at temperatures above 760 °C (1,400 °F) making it
> better-suited for use in vacuum environments.

Comment: Pure MoO3 has a listed melting point of 803C. A few impurities or slightly off temperature control…

Comment: @JonCuster : I am not sure the MoO3 melting temperature matters: if the foil gets oxidized it probably fails anyway.

Comment: It oxidizes then melts, or some complex mix of the two as the process plays out.

Comment: @JonCuster : it is difficult to understand from the photo if something melted or just turned into powder.

Comment: I think it got melted because when I opened it the remaining portion was hard solid, so it melted and resolidify. @akhmeteli